# Decode Dict in elm

Tags: elm

I have a test in elm which tries to decode a simple json structure that has an id and a map of headers. When I give 0 or one headers the test passes however with more than that the test fails with the following:

```
Test Suite: Decode an Email: FAILED
  a simple email: FAILED. Expected: Ok { id = "1234", headers = Dict.fromList [("key1","value1"),("key2","value2")] }; got: Ok { id = "1234", headers = Dict.fromList [("key1","value1"),("key2","value2")] }
```

The two results are identical, so why are they not equal according to the assertion?

Comment: Can you post the test code that generated this?

Comment: @badcook I have given up for now, apparently `==` can't be trusted with Dicts, Sets and Arrays and this is a problem that needs to be solved carefully and not just hacked. https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/403. The way I think about using Elm this is a massive downer but I accept that the language is very new and it's already awesome so I have confidence that this will be fixed fairly soon.

Comment: Add that as an answer. Answers your question exactly. In the interim you can use `toList` and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

There are a [set](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/361) of [long-standing](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/448) issues reported with a [range](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-discuss/json$20decode$20aaron/elm-discuss/meiV217ldzc/Lpc9s04EXyUJ) of datastructure with `Json.Decode`.

The following is a piece of code that generally hacks around the issue:

```
decoder : Json.Decode.Decoder (BaseValue String)
decoder =
  Json.Decode.map (\e -> Entry e) <|
  object4 (\t d i c -> {id=i, headers=h})
    ("text" := Json.Decode.string)
    ("headers" := Json.Decode.dict (lazy \_ -> decoder)))

lazy : (() -> Decoder a) -> Decoder a
lazy thunk =
  Json.Decode.customDecoder value
      (\js -> Json.Decode.decodeValue (thunk ()) js)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any chance you could explain this a little, I couldn't find any explanation on the sources you provided. Also, I still don't understand how the test failure explanation printed 2 identical things and yet it thinks that they are not identical?

Comment: I had a go at this but couldn't get it to work. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently == can't be trusted with Dicts, Sets and Arrays and this is a problem that needs to be solved carefully and not just hacked. github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/403.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `Dict` issues were addressed in Elm `0.18.0`:

https://runelm.io/c/9dt